# Creating multiple list values from for loop

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

I am trying to create a list with multiple values using this pseudo code:
for i in range(0,3), append the letter first,second and third with i and return a list with these values

desired output:

```
first1,second1,third1,first2,second2,third3
```

I have tried using itertools for this

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    ('first'+str(i),'second'+str(i),'third'+str(i))
         for i in range(1,86)))
```

However I am getting the message:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Here is the full error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-265-593da73e688e> in <module>
----> 5 col_names =list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(('first'+str(i),'second'+str(i),'third'+str(i)) for i in range(1,86)))

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: work on my end , please output print(list), I feel like you assign the value to the function list

Comment: I don't get how your psuedo code is supposed to achieve the output.  Which is the right one?

Comment: This also works fine for me under Python 3.6.8

Comment: To address your particular error, you probably have reassigned the built-in name `list` somewhere previous in your code.  Search for `list = ...` and change the `list` name to something else, like `lst`.  Don't use built-in names for variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import itertools

x=["first", "second", "third"]
y=list(range(5))

z=list(map(lambda x: f"{x[1]}{x[0]}", itertools.product(y,x)))

print(z)
```

Output:

```py
['first0', 'second0', 'third0', 'first1', 'second1', 'third1', 'first2', 'second2', 'third2', 'first3', 'second3', 'third3', 'first4', 'second4', 'third4']
```

Comment: No need for a lambda. Use `str.format`: `z=list(map("{0[0]}{0[1]}".format, product(x,y)))`

Comment: Or even simpler: `list(map(''.join, product(x,map(str, y))))`